# alignment for html5 page

Tags: html, css

the problem was i was not able to figure out the problem with my alignment 
i have tried to restrict the header banner with center top in css but this was failed and my text is not aligning to center and it was moving downwards if viewed in less resolution can any one figure out why the problem is

```
html {
min-height: 20%;
max-height: 80%;
max-width: 80%;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url();
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}

body {
min-height:80%;
width: 800px;
max-width: 90%;
margin-top:550px;
font-size: 30px;
```

}
my code css is above and the below is my site link
http://design3web.in/test1/

Comment: you don't have any markup except head and body, add some divs here and paragraphs for text

Comment: that is jst i have only 2 lines  of  text so is it needed?

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you want to achieve. To center the page, use `body { margin:auto; }` and remove `max-width: 80%;` from html

Comment: yeah centering done can u please help me with arranging  and fixing the text just below the banner in all screen resolutions